# Using \n as delimiter prints an extra empty line

Tags: java, newline, java.util.scanner, delimiter

i have following code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
input.useDelimiter("\n")
System.out.println(input.next());
System.out.println("end");
```

when i run it and type "orange apple" then enter, it will print

> orange apple
>
> end

instead of

> orange apple
> end

which is what i actually wanted to print. i have no idea why it keeps printing an extra empty line. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 5):

`System.out.println` already makes a new line as opposed to `System.out.print` which doesn't. So when `System.out.println` is used with `\n` you're making 2 new lines.

Comment: uhm sorry but i don't quite get what 'is used with \n' means...since \n is a delimiter, should it not have been excluded from what input.next() returns?

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println automatically move the cursor to next line and "\n" also do the same thing. So in your program you are using both that's why 2 new lines are entered. Either use System.out.println or use System.out.print with "\n".

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand what 'using both ways' means..i set '\n' as the delimiter so shouldn't input.next() only return "orange apple" since that's the token before the delimiter('\n')?